# Redirect to cart if cart is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, redirect

I am writing an extension for a new payment gateway. In payment controller for a validation purpose I am inspecting is there any products in cart, if not redirecting to cart. Code as below

```
<?php
     // other code goes here
     if(!$order->getId()){
         $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
     }
     // other code goes here
?>
```

But it is not redirecting to cart. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: may be your issue in !$order->getId() ... You did  not got the order object and

Comment: @AmitBera I added a simple echo inside if, its printing.

Comment: missing return ;  `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); return;`

Comment: @AmitBera yes, its good catch.. Working now.. Post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as commit missing is return. You need add return for execute redirection

```
 if(!$order->getId()){
         $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
return;
     }
```